# Is there a way how to fix this Function invocation thing?

Tags: android, android-imageview

i have this problem in my ImageView(widget android)
when everytime i call the ImageView object
from "mainact.xml" to my "mainact.kt"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wfYt.png)

it show an error

*Function invocation 'ImageView'

*None of the following functions
can be called with the arguments supplied: public constructor etc.
please help me i am new here in android studio

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView)


}
```

Comment: Can you post your code so we can help you? cheers

Comment: Share more details about the code, issue and what you tried to now.

Comment: please help me with this error.

Answer (score 0):

You’re mixing up Java and Kotlin syntax here’s what you should use:

```
val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
```